# Enhancing Accuracy of Mars Rover Current Measurements through Mechanical Isolation of Sensors

Tags: control

The current sensor of the Mars Rover made by our university students team is showing unstable current measurements due to vibrations in the terrain. How can the sensor be mechanically isolated to reduce the effect of vibration and increase accuracy? It is currently mounted directly onto the rover's chassis. And it is secured using rigid mounts. One of the initial approaches we tried was soft mounting the current sensor. It seems that this approach did not provide sufficient isolation to achieve the desired level of accuracy. We also experimented with adding tuned mass dampers to the sensor system. We found that their effectiveness was limited, likely due to the specific frequencies and magnitudes of the vibrations encountered during the rover's movements. In a more advanced attempt, we explored active vibration control techniques. While this method showed promise in controlled environments, its implementation for the rover's mission posed challenges in terms of power consumption and complexity.
Also, can you guys provide me some website links to research more about the problem?

Comment: Please [edit] and provide more info. How is it currently mounted? What vibration damping have you already tried?

Comment: `unstable current measurements` ... are you talking about electrical current?

Comment: `unstable current measurements` - seconding @jsotola's comment above - electrical current? If you find limited effectiveness that you think is `likely due to the specific frequencies and magnitudes of the vibrations encountered` then do you really have a tuned mass damper?  (Is it appropriately tuned?) How have you proven to yourself that this is due to vibration? What frequency/frequencies cause trouble? How does that relate to the vibration rating for the device (or is it rated?) Have you explored alternative sensors?

Comment: @Chuck yes, I am talking about electrical current. I am not sure about the adjustment of the TMD's parameters. To establish the cause of unstable current measurements, vibration analysis using accelerometers and other sensing equipment has been done. By analyzing the data obtained , we determined the relationship between vibrations and the fluctuations in the current sensor readings.

Comment: I can't imagine a scenario where mechanical motion is causing changes in electrical current unless the sensor is supposed to be measuring that motion, and the change in current is an output, or you're in some heavy magnetic fields, or the device is malfunctioning during vibration. What vibration rating does your sensor have? What is it supposed to be measuring?

Comment: please add a link to the current sensor data sheet

Comment: maybe the vibrations are partly caused by the current variations